# OAS for securities products

Tags: fixed-income, embedded-options

Hello I’m new to quantlib so apologies for the stupid question.

I want to calculate the OAS for various securitized products (e.g.,ABS,CMO,MBS, TBA). Is there a function to calculate the z-spread then OAS? (considering different nature of cashflow of the securities such as prepayment risk in MBS)?

Also how do you get the embedded option cost for the bond? I read it’s the option cost / face value / 1000 to change the convention to bps.